# Add customized styles and count innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular2-template, innerhtml

I need to define a css style, something like `<special> </special>`,

```
special { 
   color: #000000;
   background: #ffff00;
}
```

and use it in a innerHTML. 
However in angular it seems not easy as it have Sanitization method.
I tried use it in the following way,

```
result = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(result.trim());
```

Right now the error in console is no longer seen, although my `<special>` is still not working.

Also, when use string to do the word count, `result.length` will simply include all the characters of `<special>Hi</special>`, not just `Hi`.

How to use my `<special>` style and count the real characters that is shown? Thank you.

---

BTW I tried to use css class too, which is also not working...

```
.special { 
   color: #000000;
   background: #ffff00;
}
```

together with

```
<div class="special"> Hi </div>
```

in the string for innerHTML.

---

`<div class="special"> Hi </div>` works perfectly when not with innerHTML,
and in Chrome Developer Tools it is shown as
`<div _ngcontent-c4 class="special">Hi</div>`
Any idea of what `_ngcontent-c4` is?

Comment: Do you need to use a custom element? Can you just use a class, and then style it?

Comment: Indeed, custom elements have to be defined **first** and are rarely a good idea IMO.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Custom_Elements

Comment: @Olian04  I just tried, not working  - I didn't see that `<special>` in the css element in Chrome Developer Tools.. this is weird

Comment: `_ngcontent-c4` is part of what andular does to work its magic, don't bother with understanding why. However, if the div with your class does exist in the DOM, then the problem lies else were. Take a look at your css, maybe you're missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it using a class to style your `special` element.

```css
.special {
  display: inline;
  color: orangered;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app>
  <script type="text/javascript"
    src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js">
    </script>

  <input type="text" ng-model="sometext" /> <!--Proof that this is angualar-->
  <h1>Hello <div class="special">{{ sometext }}</div> </h1>
  
</html>
```